# Is there a way to convert my regular toilet seat to one that's like a Toto...so the seat won't slam shut?

Tags: toilet

Are there hinges out there that I can use to convert my toilet seat so that it won't slam shut?
Other methods?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Buy a new toilet seat. The big box stores sell several that are billed as "Whisper Close" "SlowClose", etc. We're talking $30-40 here (as opposed to $10-20 for a low-end toilet seat) so it's not like I'd be concerned with preserving the existing seat.

Comment: I'd be willing to bet that any sort of an "add-on" that would make an existing seat a "soft-close" seat would easily cost the same $30-40 as a full on replacement. Funny thing is, I've never seen a replacement hinge kit that promises to make your existing seat into a soft-close one. (in response to some not-an-answer questions asking about this.)

Comment: Most likely the way to get "slow close hinges for a different toilet seat" is to buy a slow-close seat, remove the hinges, transfer them, and discard the seat. Or - hold onto the seat and close it rather than slamming it or letting it drop, as has always been the case prior to such things being brought to market at all.

Comment: Toilet seat hinges are not standardized, and it is rarely possible to interchange them. It's theoretically possible for seat manufacturers to sell replacements for their models, but I've not seen that happen except for those used on some marine toilets.